# Python Parsing JSON objects from logfile

Tags: python, json, logging

Currently I am looking to parse through a logfile where each line is represented as individual JSON objects

Example:

```
{"timestamp":"2021-09-15T14:56:28Z","event":{"agentId":"Foo/2.1.0 [foo.bar.java/3.207.3]","stage":"CLOSE","type":"TEST_RESULTS","testId":["uuid"],"threadId":16,"stackTrace":"com.Foo.logSessionResultsAndThrowException()","data":{"url":"foobar","status":"Unresolved"}},"level":"Notice"}
{"timestamp":"2021-09-15T14:58:28Z","event":{"agentId":"Foo/2.1.0 [foo.bar.java/3.207.3]","stage":"CLOSE","type":"TEST_RESULTS","testId":["uuid"],"threadId":16,"stackTrace":"com.Foo.logSessionResultsAndThrowException()","data":{"url":"foobar","status":"Passed"}},"level":"Notice"}
{"timestamp":"2021-09-15T14:58:28Z","event":{"agentId":"Foo/2.1.0 [foo.bar.java/3.207.3]","stage":"CLOSE","type":"TEST_RESULTS","testId":["uuid"],"threadId":16,"stackTrace":"com.Foo.logSessionResultsAndThrowException()","data":{"url":"foobar","status":"Passed"}},"level":"Notice"}
```

Based on how it's output, I'm unable to format it as a json file

Is there a way I can do the following:

1. Read through the log file
2. Find the objects that match specific criteria (i.e., `"type":"TEST_RESULTS"`)
3. Output the lines that matched the criteria (in this case, only output the object:

```
{"timestamp":"2021-09-15T14:56:28Z","event":{"agentId":"Foo/2.1.0 [foo.bar.java/3.207.3]","stage":"CLOSE","type":"TEST_RESULTS","testId":["uuid"],"threadId":16,"stackTrace":"com.Foo.logSessionResultsAndThrowException()","data":{"url":"foobar","status":"Unresolved"}},"level":"Notice"}
```

Thanks in advance; I'm not the greatest with how Python does things

Comment: Look into JSONLines or NDJSON for the format. You just need to split on newlines and combine as you wish

Comment: In other words, it's not valid JSON but it's also not esoteric. It's designed so you can lazily parse entries